# Pass javascript function as parameter

Tags: r, datatables, dt

Is there any way to pass a javascript function as parameter using `DT::datatable()`? I'm trying to use [colvis button's](https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis) `columnText` parameter, but `datatable()` always transform the value in string.

My table is very similar to this (I use a container as head, so I can't use colnames paramater)

```
library(DT)

sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))

# Work
datatable(iris,
          extensions = c('Buttons'),
          options = list(dom = c('Bfrtip'),
                         buttons = list(list(extend = 'colvis'))
          ),
          container = sketch)


# Doesn't work
datatable(iris,
          extensions = c('Buttons'),
          options = list(dom = c('Bfrtip'),
                         buttons = list(list(extend = 'colvis',
                                             columnText = function ( dt, idx, title ) { return (idx+1) }))
          ),
          container = sketch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `JS` function:

```
 columnText = JS("function ( dt, idx, title ) { return (idx+1) }")
```